Package Installation issue while installing from requirements.txt file: ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:/
(base) C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Text_Summarizer\Text-Summarizer>pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Text_Summarizer/Text-Summarizer (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-zwvh3j1d

I am not able to install packages from requirements.txt file.

Maybe include your requirements.txt file
